# Getting incoming calls for an hour only using Twilio

Tags: android, service, twilio, android-alertdialog

I have implemented `Twilio` in my android app for outgoing and incoming calls. But I'm facing an issue while getting incoming call with the background service. The issue is that I get calls in first 30-40 mins only. After sometime phone stops getting incoming calls. I tried so much. Please respond me soon. I'm sharing code with you too.

I get token from a  background service which generates token after a time period.

IncomingCallService.java

```
public class IncomingCallService extends Service implements LoginListener,
    BasicConnectionListener, BasicDeviceListener, View.OnClickListener,
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener,
    RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

private static Handler handler, handler_login;
public IncomingPhone phone;
SharedPreferences login_details;
Vibrator vibrator;
Ringtone r;
Uri notification;
public static final String LOGIN_DETAILS = "XXXXXXXX";
AudioManager am;
Intent intent;
public static String DEFAULT_CLIENT_NAME = "developer";
static String Twilio_id = "",
        INCOMING_AUTH_PHP_SCRIPT = MenuItems.INCOMING_AUTH_PHP_SCRIPT
                + MenuItems.Twilio_id;
Runnable newrun;
Activity context;
Context ctx;
static String op_id = "";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    login_details = getSharedPreferences(LOGIN_DETAILS,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (login_details.contains("twilio_Id")) {
        Twilio_id = login_details.getString("twilio_Id", "");
    }
    handler_login = new Handler();
    handler_login.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Login();
            handler_login.postDelayed(this, 20000);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

public void Login() {
    phone = IncomingPhone.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    phone.setListeners(this, this, this);
    phone.login(DEFAULT_CLIENT_NAME, true, true);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    this.intent = intent;
    // I know getIntent always return NULL in service
    if (intent != null) {
        op_id = intent.getStringExtra("operator_id");
        onCallHandler();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void onCallHandler() {

    handler = new Handler();
    newrun = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.removeCallbacks(newrun);
            new IncomingTokenTask().execute();
            if (phone.handleIncomingIntent(intent)) {
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 2000000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(newrun, 8000000);

}

class IncomingTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    IncomingPhone.capabilityToken = EntityUtils
                            .toString(entity);              
    }


}
```

The BasicPhone class of twilio

```
public class IncomingPhone implements DeviceListener, ConnectionListener {
private static final String TAG = "IncomingPhone";
static String decodedString = "";
static String capabilityToken = "";
// TODO: change this to point to the script on your public server
private static final String AUTH_PHP_SCRIPT = MenuItems.INCOMING_AUTH_PHP_SCRIPT+MenuItems.Twilio_id;

public interface LoginListener {
    public void onLoginStarted();

    public void onLoginFinished();

    public void onLoginError(Exception error);
}

public interface BasicConnectionListener {
    public void onIncomingConnectionDisconnected();

    public void onConnectionConnecting();

    public void onConnectionConnected();

    public void onConnectionFailedConnecting(Exception error);

    public void onConnectionDisconnecting();

    public void onConnectionDisconnected();

    public void onConnectionFailed(Exception error);
}

public interface BasicDeviceListener {
    public void onDeviceStartedListening();

    public void onDeviceStoppedListening(Exception error);
}

private static IncomingPhone instance;

public static final IncomingPhone getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new IncomingPhone(context);
    return instance;
}

private final Context context;
private LoginListener loginListener;
private BasicConnectionListener basicConnectionListener;
private BasicDeviceListener basicDeviceListener;

private static boolean twilioSdkInited;
private static boolean twilioSdkInitInProgress;
private boolean queuedConnect;

private Device device;
private Connection pendingIncomingConnection;
private Connection connection;
private boolean speakerEnabled;

private String lastClientName;
private boolean lastAllowOutgoing;
private boolean lastAllowIncoming;

private IncomingPhone(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void setListeners(LoginListener loginListener,
        BasicConnectionListener basicConnectionListener,
        BasicDeviceListener basicDeviceListener) {
    this.loginListener = loginListener;
    this.basicConnectionListener = basicConnectionListener;
    this.basicDeviceListener = basicDeviceListener;
}

private void obtainCapabilityToken(String clientName,
        boolean allowOutgoing, boolean allowIncoming) {
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
    HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
    socketFactory
            .setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
    SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(
            httpclient.getParams(), registry);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr,
            httpclient.getParams());

    // Set verifier
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
    url.append(AUTH_PHP_SCRIPT);

    // This runs asynchronously!
    new GetAuthTokenAsyncTask().execute(url.toString());
}

private boolean isCapabilityTokenValid() {
    if (device == null || device.getCapabilities() == null)
        return false;
    long expTime = (Long) device.getCapabilities().get(
            Capability.EXPIRATION);
    return expTime - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 > 0;
}

//
private void updateAudioRoute() {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(speakerEnabled);
}

public void login(final String clientName, final boolean allowOutgoing,
        final boolean allowIncoming) {
    if (loginListener != null)
        loginListener.onLoginStarted();

    this.lastClientName = clientName;
    this.lastAllowOutgoing = allowOutgoing;
    this.lastAllowIncoming = allowIncoming;

    if (!twilioSdkInited) {
        if (twilioSdkInitInProgress)
            return;

        twilioSdkInitInProgress = true;
        Twilio.setLogLevel(Log.DEBUG);

        Twilio.initialize(context, new Twilio.InitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitialized() {
                twilioSdkInited = true;
                twilioSdkInitInProgress = false;
                obtainCapabilityToken(clientName, allowOutgoing,
                        allowIncoming);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception error) {
                twilioSdkInitInProgress = false;
                if (loginListener != null)
                    loginListener.onLoginError(error);
            }
        });
    } else {
        obtainCapabilityToken(clientName, allowOutgoing, allowIncoming);
    }
}

private void reallyLogin(final String capabilityToken) {
    try {
        if (device == null) {
            device = Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken, this);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, IncomingPhoneActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            device.setIncomingIntent(pendingIntent);
        } else
            device.updateCapabilityToken(capabilityToken);

        if (loginListener != null)
            loginListener.onLoginFinished();

        if (queuedConnect) {
            // If someone called connect() before we finished initializing
            // the SDK, let's take care of that here.
            connect(null);
            queuedConnect = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (device != null)
            device.release();
        device = null;

        if (loginListener != null)
            loginListener.onLoginError(e);
    }
}

public void setSpeakerEnabled(boolean speakerEnabled) {
    if (speakerEnabled != this.speakerEnabled) {
        this.speakerEnabled = speakerEnabled;
        updateAudioRoute();
    }
}

public void connect(Map<String, String> inParams) {
    if (twilioSdkInitInProgress) {
        // If someone calls connect() before the SDK is initialized, we'll
        // remember
        // that fact and try to connect later.
        queuedConnect = true;
        return;
    }

    if (!isCapabilityTokenValid())
        login(lastClientName, lastAllowOutgoing, lastAllowIncoming);

    if (device == null)
        return;

    if (canMakeOutgoing()) {
        disconnect();
        connection = device.connect(inParams, this);
        if (connection == null && basicConnectionListener != null)
            basicConnectionListener
                    .onConnectionFailedConnecting(new Exception(
                            "Couldn't create new connection"));
    }
}

public void disconnect() {
    IncomingPhoneActivity.incomingAlert = null;
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect(); // will null out in onDisconnected()
        if (basicConnectionListener != null)
            basicConnectionListener.onConnectionDisconnecting();
    }
}

public void acceptConnection() {
    if (pendingIncomingConnection != null) {
        if (connection != null)
            disconnect();

        pendingIncomingConnection.accept();
        connection = pendingIncomingConnection;
        pendingIncomingConnection = null;
    }
}

public void connecta(String phoneNumber) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Calling...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameters.put("group_id", "11");
    // String capabilityToken;
    try {
        device = Twilio
                .createDevice(decodedString, this /* DeviceListener */);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        device.disconnectAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection = device.connect(parameters, this);

    if (connection == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create new connection");
    }
}

public void ignoreIncomingConnection() {
    if (pendingIncomingConnection != null) {
        pendingIncomingConnection.ignore();
    }
}

public boolean isConnected() {
    return connection != null
            && connection.getState() == Connection.State.CONNECTED;
}

public Connection.State getConnectionState() {
    return connection != null ? connection.getState()
            : Connection.State.DISCONNECTED;
}

public boolean hasPendingConnection() {
    return pendingIncomingConnection != null;
}

public boolean handleIncomingIntent(Intent intent) {
    Device inDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(Device.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    Connection inConnection = intent
            .getParcelableExtra(Device.EXTRA_CONNECTION);
    if (inDevice == null && inConnection == null)
        return false;

    intent.removeExtra(Device.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    intent.removeExtra(Device.EXTRA_CONNECTION);

    if (pendingIncomingConnection != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "A pending connection already exists");
        inConnection.ignore();
        return false;
    }

    pendingIncomingConnection = inConnection;
    pendingIncomingConnection.setConnectionListener(this);

    return true;
}

public boolean canMakeOutgoing() {
    if (device == null)
        return false;

    Map<Capability, Object> caps = device.getCapabilities();
    return caps.containsKey(Capability.OUTGOING)
            && (Boolean) caps.get(Capability.OUTGOING);
}

public boolean canAcceptIncoming() {
    if (device == null)
        return false;

    Map<Capability, Object> caps = device.getCapabilities();
    return caps.containsKey(Capability.INCOMING)
            && (Boolean) caps.get(Capability.INCOMING);
}

public void setCallMuted(boolean isMuted) {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.setMuted(isMuted);
    }
}

@Override
/* DeviceListener */
public void onStartListening(Device inDevice) {
    if (basicDeviceListener != null)
        basicDeviceListener.onDeviceStartedListening();
}

@Override
/* DeviceListener */
public void onStopListening(Device inDevice) {
    if (basicDeviceListener != null)
        basicDeviceListener.onDeviceStoppedListening(null);
}

@Override
/* DeviceListener */
public void onStopListening(Device inDevice, int inErrorCode,
        String inErrorMessage) {
    if (basicDeviceListener != null)
        basicDeviceListener.onDeviceStoppedListening(new Exception(
                inErrorMessage));
}

@Override
/* DeviceListener */
public boolean receivePresenceEvents(Device inDevice) {
    return false;
}

@Override
/* DeviceListener */
public void onPresenceChanged(Device inDevice, PresenceEvent inPresenceEvent) {
}

@Override
/* ConnectionListener */
public void onConnecting(Connection inConnection) {
    if (basicConnectionListener != null)
        basicConnectionListener.onConnectionConnecting();
}

@Override
/* ConnectionListener */
public void onConnected(Connection inConnection) {
    updateAudioRoute();
    if (basicConnectionListener != null)
        basicConnectionListener.onConnectionConnected();
}

@Override
/* ConnectionListener */
public void onDisconnected(Connection inConnection) {
    if (inConnection == connection) {
        connection = null;
        if (basicConnectionListener != null)
            basicConnectionListener.onConnectionDisconnected();
    } else if (inConnection == pendingIncomingConnection) {
        pendingIncomingConnection = null;
        if (basicConnectionListener != null)
            basicConnectionListener.onIncomingConnectionDisconnected();
    }
}

@Override
/* ConnectionListener */
public void onDisconnected(Connection inConnection, int inErrorCode,
        String inErrorMessage) {
    if (inConnection == connection) {
        connection = null;
        if (basicConnectionListener != null)
            basicConnectionListener
                    .onConnectionFailedConnecting(new Exception(
                            inErrorMessage));
    }
}

private class GetAuthTokenAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>         {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        IncomingPhone.this.reallyLogin(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            capabilityToken = HttpHelper.httpGet(params[0]);
            decodedString = capabilityToken.replace("\"", "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decodedString;
    }
}
}
```

And the activity which opens after getting incoming call via Service class.

```
public class IncomingPhoneActivity extends Activity implements LoginListener,
    BasicConnectionListener, BasicDeviceListener, View.OnClickListener,
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener,
    RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {
private static final Handler handler = new Handler();
public IncomingPhone phone;
SharedPreferences login_details;
Vibrator vibrator;
private LinearLayout disconnect_btn;
private LinearLayout mainButton;
private ToggleButton speakerButton;
private ToggleButton muteButton;
private EditText logTextBox;
static AlertDialog incomingAlert;
private EditText outgoingTextBox;
private EditText clientNameTextBox;
private Button capabilitesButton;
private CheckBox incomingCheckBox, outgoingCheckBox;
Button call_btn, dis_call_btn, updateButton;
public static String AUTH_PHP_SCRIPT, rating1, rating2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.call_screen);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Operator_id = intent.getStringExtra("operator_id");
    gps = new GPSTracker(IncomingPhoneActivity.this);
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
    } else {
        // gps.showSettingsAlert();
        latitude = 0.00;
        longitude = 0.00;
    }
    login_details = getSharedPreferences(LOGIN_DETAILS,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (login_details.contains("twilio_Id")) {
        Twilio_id = login_details.getString("twilio_Id", "");
    }
    AUTH_PHP_SCRIPT = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/getGenToken?group_id="
            + Operator_id + "&twilio_id=" + Twilio_id + "&latitude="
            + latitude + "&longitude=" + longitude;

    disconnect_btn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.d_call);
    mainButton = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.call);
    call_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call_btn);
    dis_call_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d_call_btn);
    mainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    call_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    dis_call_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    disconnect_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    mainButton.setEnabled(false);
    call_btn.setEnabled(false);
    speakerButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.speaker_btn);
    speakerButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    muteButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.mute_btn);
    muteButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    logTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.log_text_box);
    outgoingTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.outgoing_client);
    clientNameTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.client_name);
    clientNameTextBox.setText(DEFAULT_CLIENT_NAME);
    capabilitesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capabilites_button);
    capabilitesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    outgoingCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.outgoing);
    incomingCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.incoming);
    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    if (MenuItems.Speaker == true) {
        speakerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        speakerButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    phone = IncomingPhone.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    phone.setListeners(this, this, this);
    phone.login(DEFAULT_CLIENT_NAME, outgoingCheckBox.isChecked(),
            incomingCheckBox.isChecked());

}

private void syncMainButton() {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (IncomingPhone.decodedString.length() != 0) {
                if (phone.isConnected()) {
                    switch (phone.getConnectionState()) {
                    default:
                        mainButton.setClickable(true);
                        mainButton.setEnabled(true);
                        call_btn.setEnabled(true);
                        mainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        disconnect_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        disconnect_btn.setClickable(false);
                        break;
                    case DISCONNECTED:
                        mainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        disconnect_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        disconnect_btn.setClickable(false);
                        break;
                    case CONNECTED:
                        mainButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        disconnect_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        disconnect_btn.setClickable(true);
                        break;
                    case CONNECTING:
                        mainButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        disconnect_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        disconnect_btn.setClickable(true);
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (phone.hasPendingConnection()) {
                    mainButton.setClickable(true);
                    mainButton.setEnabled(true);
                    call_btn.setEnabled(true);
                    mainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    disconnect_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    disconnect_btn.setClickable(false);
                } else {
                    mainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    disconnect_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    disconnect_btn.setClickable(false);
                }
                /*
                 * else { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                 * "TRY AGAIN!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
                 */
            }

        }
    });
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    phone.disconnect();
    incomingAlert = null;
    Intent in = new Intent(IncomingPhoneActivity.this, MenuItems.class);
    in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(in);
    finish();
}

class TokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String message;
    JSONObject jsonResponse;
    int crash_app;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(AUTH_PHP_SCRIPT);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    IncomingPhone.capabilityToken = EntityUtils
                            .toString(entity);
                    IncomingPhone.decodedString = IncomingPhone.capabilityToken
                            .replace("\"", "");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            crash_app = 5;
            message = "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if (status.equals("success")) {

            final Handler handler12 = new Handler();
            handler12.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mainButton.setEnabled(true);
                    call_btn.setEnabled(true);
                    mainButton
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_green_connect);

                }
            }, 3000);

        }
        if (status.equals("failure")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // mainButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4ca64c"));
            mainButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dark_green_connect);
            mainButton.setEnabled(false);
            call_btn.setEnabled(false);

        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (phone.handleIncomingIntent(getIntent())) {
        showIncomingAlert();
        addStatusMessage(R.string.got_incoming);
        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(IncomingPhoneActivity.this)) {
            syncMainButton();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(IncomingPhoneActivity.this,
                    "No internet connection!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (phone != null) {
        phone.setListeners(null, null, null);
        phone = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if ((view.getId() == R.id.d_call) || (view.getId() == R.id.d_call_btn)) {
        phone.disconnect();
        incomingAlert = null;
        phone.setSpeakerEnabled(false);
        phone.setCallMuted(false);
        Intent in = new Intent(IncomingPhoneActivity.this, MenuItems.class);
        startActivity(in);
        finish();
    }
    if ((view.getId() == R.id.call) || (view.getId() == R.id.call_btn)) {
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.capabilites_button) {
        phone.login(clientNameTextBox.getText().toString(),
                outgoingCheckBox.isChecked(), incomingCheckBox.isChecked());
    }
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    if (group.getId() == R.id.input_select) {
        if (checkedId == R.id.input_number) {
            outgoingTextBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
            outgoingTextBox.setHint(R.string.outgoing_number);
        } else {
            outgoingTextBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            outgoingTextBox.setHint(R.string.outgoing_client);
        }
        outgoingTextBox.setText("");
    }
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean isChecked) {
    if (button.getId() == R.id.speaker_btn) {
        phone.setSpeakerEnabled(isChecked);
    } else if (button.getId() == R.id.mute_btn) {
        phone.setCallMuted(isChecked);
    }
}

private void addStatusMessage(final String message) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            logTextBox.append('-' + message + '\n');
        }
    });
}

private void addStatusMessage(int stringId) {
    addStatusMessage(getString(stringId));
}

private void showIncomingAlert() {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (incomingAlert == null) {
                notification = RingtoneManager
                        .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),
                        notification);
                am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
                    r.play();
                    break;
                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                    long pattern[] = { 0, 500, 200, 300, 500 };
                    vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);
                    break;
                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                    r.play();
                    break;
                }
                incomingAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        IncomingPhoneActivity.this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.incoming_call)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setMessage(R.string.incoming_call_message)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.answer,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
                                        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
                                            r.stop();
                                            break;
                                        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                                            vibrator.cancel();
                                            break;
                                        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                                            r.stop();
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        phone.acceptConnection();
                                        disconnect_btn
                                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        mainButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        incomingAlert = null;

                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.ignore,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
                                        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
                                            r.stop();
                                            break;
                                        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                                            vibrator.cancel();
                                            break;
                                        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                                            r.stop();
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        phone.ignoreIncomingConnection();
                                        incomingAlert = null;
                                    }
                                })
                        .setOnCancelListener(
                                new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancel(
                                            DialogInterface dialog) {
                                        phone.ignoreIncomingConnection();
                                    }
                                }).create();
                incomingAlert.show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void hideIncomingAlert() {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (incomingAlert != null) {
                incomingAlert.dismiss();
                incomingAlert = null;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onLoginStarted() {
    addStatusMessage(R.string.logging_in);
}

@Override
public void onLoginFinished() {
    addStatusMessage(phone.canMakeOutgoing() ? R.string.outgoing_ok
            : R.string.no_outgoing_capability);
    addStatusMessage(phone.canAcceptIncoming() ? R.string.incoming_ok
            : R.string.no_incoming_capability);
    syncMainButton();
}

@Override
public void onLoginError(Exception error) {
    if (error != null)
        addStatusMessage(String.format(getString(R.string.login_error_fmt),
                error.getLocalizedMessage()));
    else
        addStatusMessage(R.string.login_error_unknown);
    syncMainButton();
}

@Override
public void onIncomingConnectionDisconnected() {
    hideIncomingAlert();
    addStatusMessage(R.string.incoming_disconnected);
    syncMainButton();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionConnecting() {
    addStatusMessage(R.string.attempting_to_connect);
    syncMainButton();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionConnected() {
    addStatusMessage(R.string.connected);
    syncMainButton();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailedConnecting(Exception error) {
    if (error != null)
        addStatusMessage(String.format(
                getString(R.string.couldnt_establish_outgoing_fmt),
                error.getLocalizedMessage()));
    else
        addStatusMessage(R.string.couldnt_establish_outgoing);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionDisconnecting() {
    addStatusMessage(R.string.disconnect_attempt);
    syncMainButton();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionDisconnected() {
    addStatusMessage(R.string.disconnected);
    syncMainButton();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(Exception error) {
    if (error != null)
        addStatusMessage(String.format(
                getString(R.string.connection_error_fmt),
                error.getLocalizedMessage()));
    else
        addStatusMessage(R.string.connection_error);
    syncMainButton();
}

@Override
public void onDeviceStartedListening() {
    addStatusMessage(R.string.device_listening);
}

@Override
public void onDeviceStoppedListening(Exception error) {
    if (error != null)
        addStatusMessage(String.format(
                getString(R.string.device_listening_error_fmt),
                error.getLocalizedMessage()));
    else
        addStatusMessage(R.string.device_not_listening);
}
}
```

Comment: @maveň edited, you can check now.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but could it be that you aren't having a twilio issue, but an issue with the app (and the background service) becoming inactive? Something pertaining to Android battery management possibly...

Comment: @ThereseStirling yea it was phone's specific issue.